# Connecting Android phone to OSX mac computer

Tags: usb, connection-issues, usb-connection-mode

I've had trouble connecting my android (The Nextbit Robin) to my computer. I am pretty sure it's an Android 6.0 issue. I have been able to get it to work by enabling USB debugging and selecting MTP on USB configuration. However when I tried to do that again it just selected 'Charging only', even when selecting any other setting. I clueless as to what to do. Does anyone know how to fix this? By the way, I should mention that I am using android file transfer.

Thanks.

Comment: Let me see what I can find out.  I have a S7 Edge on 6.0.1 and noticed similar behavior on my iMac. I haven't approached it again.
Rick

Comment: I found the problem. The issue was with my computer.

Comment: However, I still can't connect it to my computer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should note that I have no idea why this worked, but it did.

I made a partition in my computer's memory. Then I installed a separate version of OSX. When I booted to that partition the Robin connected flawlessly. I thought that it would only work in the partition I created, however, when I booted back to the default partition, the Robin connected.

For perspective, here is a list of the things I tried before I got it to work:

- Fast booting the Robin.
- Rebooting the Robin.
- Wiping the cache of the Robin.
- Restarting my computer.
- Clearing the SMC and NVRAM of the computer.
- Turning on usb debugging.
- Switching between usb modes in developer options.
- Probing the usb ports in my computer (software).
- Disconnecting and connecting the usb several times out of pure frustration.
- Connecting the Robin to another computer (it connected).
- Uninstalling Android file transfer and reinstalling it.

Hopefully one of these things will work, if someone has this problem in the future.